# Какая разница как использовать токен

Tags: php, laravel

```
Authorization : Bearer myToken
Authorization : myToken
```

Я использую второй вариант. Какая разница между первым и вторым? Кто может объяснить?

Вот например как я беру объекты с базы:

```
$objects = MyObject::whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($authorization){
            return $query->where('api_token', $authorization);
        })->offset($request->get('start'))->limit($request->get('length'))->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница в том что есть несколько типов авторизации и первый способ является правильным со стороны стандартов

[https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Заголовки/Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/Authorization)